# How to create user access token for guest user to verify with AUTH:API middleware for API routes in Laravel

Tags: laravel-8, access-token, laravel-passport, bearer-token, laravel-middleware

I want to verify bearer token for GUEST users in LARAVEL API so how can I generate user access token for guest users and also verify in AUTH:API middleware